# Difference between catch up and getHealth

Tags: validator

What is the difference between getHealth and the catch up command? With my validator, I
never lag behind with the catch up command. With getHealth, it is always constant 200-300 root slots behind and the distance remains so. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementations are slightly different, so it's possible to see this situation unfortunately.

- `solana catchup` essentially compares the confirmed slot of your node to the confirmed slot of your configured RPC client (ie api.mainnet-beta.solana.com)
- `getHealth` compares your node's confirmed slot to the known validators specified in your startup parameters

This means that if your configured RPC endpoint *and* your node are both behind, `solana catchup` can report a false positive.  `getHealth` then checks relative to the known validators, which may be much further ahead.

The public endpoints tend to fall behind due to load, so this situation might be pretty common.